# How to explicitly request dialog to show up when getting auth token in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm making an Chrome Extension for gmail, and when I run this snippet of code for first time,everything is fine, dialog shows up and asks user which account to use and token gets stored and I can use the gmail API from my extension:

```
var access_token = "";
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true },
        function(token) {
            if (!!token) {
                access_token = token;
                gapi.auth.setToken({ access_token: token });                 
            }
        }
    );
```

but when I remove the token with this snippet of code:

```
chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({ token: access_token }, function() {
            console.log('token removed');                
        });
```

and I want to get token again using the first snippet, it updates the token itself, without showing dialog to user to choose which account to use.
How can I force it to show dialog?

Comment: Can you try [revoking the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)?

Comment: That did it, thanks! After making GET to "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token="+access_token
and calling first snippet of code after that, user is presented with dialog again! Please write this as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, you need to [revoke the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) to completely remove the stored credentials.

```
   curl -H "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
        https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```